# Mixing Jade and Polymer, how do I add an attribute to the body tag in jade?

Tags: class, tags, attributes, pug, polymer

I need  to call `<body unresolved></body>`. ("The unresolved attribute on the  element is used to prevent a flash of unstyled content (FOUC) on browsers that lack native support for custom elements.")

When I do this with Jade's body.unresolved, it generates as `<body class="unresolved"></body>`, so it's probably not the same as that's a class and the former is an attribute.

How do I add an attribute to the body tag in jade?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, periods are for classes, brackets are for attributes. So I had to use `body(unresolved)`

This helped: http://jade-lang.com/reference/attributes/